# changing the sourcetable of a linked table in access 2007 with C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, oledb

I'll start by asking am I right in thinking that in the image below:
[image]

the 'TABLE=CLOASEUCDBA.T_BASIC_POLICY' is not part of the connection string? in fact it is the source table name?

I'm looking to alter this to another linked table on the same database. The connection string should there be the same and the name that appears in ACCESS should be the same. The only difference should be under the hood it is actually referencing another table and of course if you open the table it will contain different fields and data.

my code for far to do this is:

```
    var dbe = new DBEngine();
    Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Test.accdb");
    foreach (TableDef tbd in db.TableDefs)
    {

        if (tbd.Name.Contains("CLOASEUCDBA_T_BASIC_POLICY"))
        {
            tbd.SourceTableName = "CLOASEUCDBA_T_BILLING_INFORMATION"; 
        }
    }
    db.Close();
```

However I'm getting a big fat COMException "Cannot set this property once the object is part of a collection.". I'm not sure exactly why and all the examples I can find online are all written in VB/VBA and I only have very very limited exposure to this. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I have tried to go a different route with no futher success using the code:

```
        if (tbd.Name.Contains("CLOASEUCDBA_T_BASIC_POLICY"))
        {
            var newtable = db.CreateTableDef("this is a new table");
            newtable.Name = "new table";
            newtable.Connect = tbd.Connect;
            newtable.SourceTableName = "CLOASEUCDBA_T_BILLING_INFORMATION";
            db.TableDefs.Append(newtable);
            //tbd.SourceTableName = "CLOASEUCDBA_T_BILLING_INFORMATION"; 
        }
```

In this case I get the error "ODBC--call failed."

Comment: **(1)** Yes, you are correct: The `TABLE=` name that appears in the ToolTip is not part of the `.Connect` property. It is the `.SourceTableName`. **(2)** Are you sure that `tbd.Connect` is a valid `.Connect` property? When you open the database in Access and double-click the corresponding linked table does it open correctly in Datasheet view? **(3)** Does the existing linked table have a database password saved as part of the linked table definition?

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I just tested your `CreateTableDef` code and it worked fine for me with linked tables pointing to both SQL Server 2008 R2 and MySQL 5.6 databases. What database backend are you using to run your tests? Perhaps there is something particular about that ODBC driver and/or its connection strings?

Comment: (2) Yes it is definitely a valid .Connect statement. I can view all the data in the datasheet mode and design mood ect. (3) the existing table does have a password saved as part of the table definition. By default access does not show this in the tooltip for obvious reasons but it is it is possible to see it with Console.Writeline(tbd.Connect);. My apologies with the CreateTableDef . I had the wrong source table name in. there was an underscore instead of a fullstop in the string. It IS working.

Comment: I dont actually want the new table to be called "new table". I need it to be called 'CLOASEUCDBA_T_BASIC_POLICY'. If I try do this in the second method, I get an exception that this already exists. Ideally I need the first way to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since we're not allowed to change the `SourceTableName` of a `TableDef` object that already exists in the `TableDefs` collection we need to create a new `TableDef` object, `.Delete` the old one, and then `.Append` the new one:

```csharp
// This code requires the following COM reference in your project:
//
//     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
// and the declaration
//
//     using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;
//
// at the top of the class file            

string tableDefName = "CLOASEUCDBA_T_BASIC_POLICY";
var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Test.accdb");
var tbdOld = db.TableDefs[tableDefName];
var tbdNew = db.CreateTableDef(tableDefName);
tbdNew.Connect = tbdOld.Connect;
tbdNew.SourceTableName = "CLOASEUCDBA_T_BILLING_INFORMATION";
db.TableDefs.Delete(tableDefName);  // remove the old TableDef ...
db.TableDefs.Append(tbdNew);        // ... and append the new one
db.Close();
```